# как отправить данные из html в python?

Tags: python-3.x, html5, django

нужно отправить id по нажатию кнопки в python словарь для того, чтобы сделать корзину на сайте. моя попытка:
cat_of_plants.html:

```
{% extends 'main_page/main_page.html' %}
{% block content %}
  <div class="container-content">
    {% for pl in plant %}
      <div class="container-content-block">
        <div class="text">{{ pl.latin_name }}</div>
        <div class="image">
          <img src="/{{ pl.image.url }}/" alt="картинка не работает" width="170" height="200">
        </div>
        <div class="text">{{ pl.price }} руб</div>
        <div class="text">{{ pl.name }}</div>
        <form action="{% url 'add_to_basket' pl.id %}" method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="В корзину">
        </form>
        <a href="{% url 'plants_info' pl.id %}">
          <input class="btn btn-light" type="submit" value="Подробнее">
        </a>
        <!-- <input class="btn btn-success" value="В корзину" type="submit"> -->
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('cat_of_plants/', cat_of_plants),
    path('basket/', basket, name='basket'),
    path('',add_to_basket, name='add_to_basket'),
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import PlantsForm
from .models import plants, shrimp, snag, snail
# Create your views here.
goods = []
def cat_of_plants(request):
    Plants = plants.objects.all()
    return render(request,'content/cat_of_plants.html',context = {'plant': Plants})
def basket(request):
    for good in goods:
        basket_elements = plants.objects.get(id = '{}'.format(good))
    return render(request,'content/basket.html', context = {'basket_elements':basket_elements})
def add_to_basket(request, id):
    if (request.method == 'POST'):
        print(request.POST)
    goods.append(id)
    return render(request, 'content/cat_of_plants.html')
```

это все выводит мне ошибку NoReverseMatch at /content/cat_of_plants/
Reverse for 'add_to_basket' with arguments '(2,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['content/$']

Comment: Укажите место в коде, где именно происходит то, что описано в вопросе и скажите, что не так с Вашей попыткой.

Comment: У вас паттерн `add_to_basket` ничего не принимает, а вы пытаетесь передать ему `pl.id`.